# Handle charge decline during app installation on Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm trying to not allow users access to my app if they decline the payment charge. If the charge was declined then the app shouldn't be installed.

**From Shopify API doc, there is return_url when the charge was accepted:**

> "return_url": "http://super-duper.shopifyapps.com"
>
> The URL where the merchant is redirected after accepting the charge.

But, when the charge was declined, Shopify only redirects user to the Apps tab in store. https://www.screencast.com/t/yCykunWY

**Is there any way to handle if the charge was declined?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

First of all, visit the following [page](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/confirm-declined-recurring-charge/m-p/1301938#M40120) from the official Shopify forum and where you will find a summary of the "charge workflow".

Now, let say that you are using the REST API in order to [create recurring application charge](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/recurringapplicationcharge#post-recurring-application-charges). According to the documentation, if there is no error, a typical response should look like that:

```json
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
{
  "recurring_application_charge": {
    "id": 1029266959,
    "name": "Super Duper Plan",
    "api_client_id": 755357713,
    "price": "10.00",
    "status": "pending",
    "return_url": "http://super-duper.shopifyapps.com/",
    "billing_on": null,
    "created_at": "2022-04-05T13:28:11-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-04-05T13:28:11-04:00",
    "test": null,
    "activated_on": null,
    "cancelled_on": null,
    "trial_days": 0,
    "trial_ends_on": null,
    "decorated_return_url": "http://super-duper.shopifyapps.com/?charge_id=1029266959",
    "confirmation_url": "https://jsmith.myshopify.com/admin/charges/755357713/1029266959/RecurringApplicationCharge/confirm_recurring_application_charge?signature=BAh7BzoHaWRpBA9eWT06EmF1dG9fYWN0aXZhdGVU--f6da6826caf9441c9fc206dd50a0882bd41fd770"
  }
}
```

There are at least two parameters you shall keep in your records (most likely in a data base together with a relation with the corresponding shop): the `status` (which is `active` if the merchant accepted the subscription) and the `id` of the charge.

Now, next time the merchant attempts to use your app, before allowing access to your app, check from your records if the `status` is `active`. If not make a request to update the status using the [Retrieve a single charge](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/recurringapplicationcharge#get-recurring-application-charges-recurring-application-charge-id) endpoint with the charge `id` you got when you created the charge. if it is still not  `active` keep denying access. You may also create a new charge and point the merchant to that charge's page so he can accept the subscription this time.